# Access to XMLHttpRequest at XXX from orgin in laravel6 and angular 8

Tags: php, angular, laravel, http-headers

I use laravel6 and angular 8
I want send POST request in angular project to server by an API
but after OPTION request method and give an error in chrome browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/register'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I created a middleware in App\Http\Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
}
```

then define middleware in kernel : app/Http/kernel.php

```
 'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

and define route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user','middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
  Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login');
  Route::post('register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('getUser', 'Api\AuthController@getUser');
  });
});
```

But again I get the same Error
Please help me solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first create cors middleware, for example

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class Cors
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
            ];

            if($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
                // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
                return \response('', 200, $headers);
            }

            $response = $next($request);
            foreach($headers as $key => $value)
                $response->header($key, $value);
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

then add in Http/Kernel.php in array $middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // other middlewares
        Cors::class
    ];
```

After it all requests with type OPTIONS will return response 200 with headers.

Comment: array $middleware or $routeMiddleware? I use your middleware code but dont work

Comment: array $middleware

Comment: show me your kernel file, route file, and headers which you send from client

Comment: It is in the same state as before, but now there are two OPTION requests, one in satus 200 and one in status 500

Comment: I sent the photos as an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing "http://localhost:4200" to "*" ,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
}
```

And register it at app/Http/kernel.php file.

Comment: I had tried this but I had the same error! also It's not safe to use the star

Comment: @kamal have you tried to register it in app/Http/kernel.php. Hope https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1 helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added my code images for help for you
I think I did everything right but my problem is not solved
Please check the photos I sent so you may find out I'm wrong

[image: this is my API code]

[image: And this is kernel code]

[image: I use base service for send POST request in Angular]

[image: and I use Interceptor for handle Http error]

[image: my error]

Comment: in kernel add
use App\Http\Middleware\Cors;

Comment: then remove cors middleware from route file and clear route cache